# configure disk usage in percentage at pipeline.yaml in ceilometer

Tags: ceilometer

How to configure in `etc/ceilometer/pipeline.yaml` to get the `disk.device.usage` in percentage for every 600 seconds.

**Configuration Details**

```
virsh # version
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.17
Using library: libvirt 1.2.17
Using API: QEMU 1.2.17
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the metrics name and interval in **source** section, define the post action in **sink** section.

You can write the yaml file like this:

```
---
sources:
    - name: meter_source
      interval: 600
      meters:
          - "disk.device.usage"
      sinks:
          - meter_sink
sinks:
    - name: meter_sink
      transformers:
      publishers:
          - notifier://
```

For more pipeline code logic and data processing mechanism, you shall read the code and related annotation in the source code files.

Comment: my requirement is to get disk.device.usage in percentage . I had tried below but it is not working 
- name: disk_usage_sink
      transformers:
          - name: "arithmetic"
            parameters:
                target:
                    name: "disk_device_usage"
                    unit: "%"
                    type: "gauge"
                    expr: "100 * $(disk.device.usage) / $(disk.device.allocation)"
      publishers:
          - notifier://

Comment: Don't see anything weird about your transformer definition, maybe you should track the logs for more details, and then check the configuration about notification agent which should work on partitioning mode(`workload_partitioning=True`).